# How to sub directory project redirecting multiple old pages to new pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, subdirectory

I'm have subfolder opencart website

.php redirect without .php

Here is an example of some of the following pages I need to move, basically anything in the pages folder needs to be moved down, also the old pages always redirect witout php.

> http://www.example.com/subfolder/login.php to
>   http://www.example.com/subfolder/login
>
> http://www.example.com/subfolder/register.php to
>   http://www.example.com/subfolder/register
>
> http://www.example.com/subfolder/account.php to
>   http://www.example.com/subfolder/account

Here is my htaccess :

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 
# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess
# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

redirect 301 /login.php http://www.example.com/subfolder/login
```

i will try above code. but nothing work properly

Comment: which opencart version you have ?

Comment: opencart 3020 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this post is regarding 301 Redirects with OpenCart 1.5 greater or Opencart 2.0 or greater.

Are you having a problem with your OpenCart SEO? Are you trying to add 301 Redirects?

Are you getting ?*route*= added to the end of your redirects and Error Not Found Message?

There are two ways to fix, that will work, it does however still change the target URL, you have to add ? yes a question mark!

**First:**

Here’s an example of what you need to use for a 301 Redirect in OpenCart .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder/login.php  http://www.example.com/subfolder/login?
Redirect 301 /subfolder/register.php  http://www.example.com/subfolder/register?
Redirect 301 /subfolder/account.php  http://www.example.com/subfolder/account?
```

**OR**

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder/login.php  http://www.example.com/subfolder/login/?
Redirect 301 /subfolder/register.php  http://www.example.com/subfolder/register/?
Redirect 301 /subfolder/account.php  http://www.example.com/subfolder/account/?
```

**Second:**

just add below line in .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 ^subfolder/login.php$  http://www.example.com/subfolder/login [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 ^subfolder/register.php$  http://www.example.com/subfolder/register [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 ^subfolder/account.php$  http://www.example.com/subfolder/account [R=301,L]
```

**I hope it's working fine.**

Comment: Nice Working For me. Thanks a lot dear.